# Check the activity of my public ipynb on Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I wrote a notebook (ipynb) on Google Colab, and sharing the link of it with other people.
Is there any way to obtain the history or frequency that others have run my notebook?

It's ok to assume that others will not modify my notebook, so you can embed some python code in the notebook, if there is no other way, but I want to use a secure method in that case.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the activity from `Google Drive API` if your notebook is saved in Google Drive.

```py
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

file_id = 'your_file_id'
results = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields="*").execute()
print(results['viewers'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, my notebook is not saved in Google Drive, but on Github – like this one.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/sokrypton/ColabFold/blob/main/AlphaFold2.ipynb
Do you have any idea of how to get the activity in that case?